# Relationship between Internal direct product and External direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

Can somemone explain to me why the internal and external direct products are essentially the same thing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Then $G$ is the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$ if 
(i) $H$ and $K$ both are normal subgroups of $G$
(ii)$G=HK$
(iii)$H\cap K=\{e\}$

Let $G_1,G_2$ be groups. Then a group $G$ is the external direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ if $G=G_1\times G_2$.

Define $\phi:G\rightarrow H\times K$ by $\phi(hk)=(h,k)$ for every $hk\in G$. It can be checked that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. Hence we can say that the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$ is **isomorphic** to the external direct product of $H$ and $K$.

On the other hand, given $H\times K$, you can check that $H\times\{e\}$ and $\{e\}\times K$ satisfies the three conditions of internal direct product. In other words, we can say that $H\times K$ is the internal direct product of $H\times\{e\}$ and $\{e\}\times K$. And of course, $H\times\{e\}\cong H$ and $\{e\}\times K\cong K$.

Comment: Yes in fact i know all of this but i can't feel really this.